# How to add new packages to CygwinPortable on a machine without Admin access

Tags: cygwin, updates, portable

I am on a Win10 machine without admin access.  I am running CygwinPortable, and would like to install the CMake package for it.  The Cygwin setup utility is missing for the portable installation.

So how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Got to the Cygwin site https://www.cygwin.com/install.html.
2. Download the `setup-x86_64.exe`.  This is the Cygwin update utility.
3. Open a bash prompt via CygwinPortable.
4. Change the working directory to the one where you downloaded `setup-x86_64.exe`.
5. Then run the Cygwin update as follows: `$ ./setup-x86_64.exe --no-admin`
6. This will invoke the Cygwin update GUI
7. Update using the GUI as per the standard process.